# Access IP Address of Hotspot device on client device in Android

Tags: android, wifi, ip-address

I am developing an Android Application in which I am using `WIFI Hotspot`. In this application I want to acquire `IP address` of Hotspot device.
The scenario is:

1) I have `device A` which is put on `Hotspot`.

2) Now I have `device B` which is connected to `device A` through `hotspot`.

3) I want to acquire `IP address` of `device A` on `device B`.

First thing is it possible? If yes, then please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey may be you are looking for router address.

Here is the code which will give you address of `Device A` on `Device B`

```
final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) super.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
final DhcpInfo dhcp = manager.getDhcpInfo();
final String address = Formatter.formatIpAddress(dhcp.gateway);
```

Comment: that's true @Sandy,... but how about if I want to get the clients IP address who connect to the Device-A ? I mean how the Device-A could detect its client?